# How to set legend chart.js text is getting cut

Tags: angular, chart.js, bar-chart

[image]

How remove space from left and right side of bar so legend get displayed with complete text

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using a custom element as legends, in this case, you can style your legend as normal as your component